# What is the problem with my manually created length function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, runtime-error

I am trying to create a length function by myself in Haskell, but when I try to execute it with any type of the list, it says "non exhaustive patterns"
What is the problem?

I tried "func [1] 0" and it was supposed to recursively call "func" once and then return y, because it is "func [] y = y". However, it gives me "non exhaustive patterns"

```
func list y = func (tail list) (y+1)
func [] y = y
```

Comment: And what is your code exactly ? For lists, you have 2 possible patterns: `[]` and `(x:xs)`

Comment: @jpmarinier yes I am trying to modify the question so that I can add the code, but I cannot find where I can do that.
My code is 

func list y = func (tail list) (y+1)
func [] y = y

Comment: @malai_320 [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76079539/edit) link is right below the question.

Comment: You should see an `Edit` button.

Comment: I added the code to my question. I also noticed that if we remove 'y' from the function, it still gives the same exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert the order of the two equations. They are tried in order, and the first one matches any `list`, including the empty list, so the second equation is never taken.

You should always turn warnings on. GHC warns about this specific mistake, pointing out that the second equation is never taken.

Also, if you use GHCi, be sure to write both equations in an .hs file and to `:load` it in GHCi. If you instead enter both equations one after the other at GHCi prompt the second one will overwrite the first one (GHCi assumes you want to redefine the function with a new definition).

Comment: Thanks! I was working in the GHCi prompt instead of a separate .hs file, that was the problem

Comment: Note you can enter multiline code into GHCi by enclosing the code lines between the `:{` and `:}` commands.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to chi's correct answer, if you use pattern-matching to extract the tail of the list rather than simply matching the name `list` to the first argument, you don't need to reorder anything.

```
func (_:tail) y = func tail (y+1)
func [] y = y
```

The `(_:tail)` pattern specifies a list which is specifically *not* empty and binds the name `tail` to its tail.

Though as a matter of opinion, I find it at least somewhat easier to understand a recursive function if the base case occurs first.